How can I count integer triplets $(x, y, z)$ with conditions on divisors, ordering, and coprimality?
I'm working on a number theory problem where I need to count the number of ordered triplets $(x, y, z)$ of integers that satisfy the following conditions:

$0 \leq x < y$,
$0 < z$,
$\operatorname{GCD}(x, y, z) = 1$,
and $y \cdot z = n$, where $n$ is a given positive integer.

For example, if $n = 12$, I want to find all triplets $(x, y, z)$ that satisfy these properties and then count them.
So far, I understand that $y$ and $z$ must be divisors of $n$ and that $x$ needs to be coprime to $y$. But I'm struggling to find an efficient way to count these triplets without brute-forcing all possible values of $(x, y, z)$, which is slow for large $n$.
I've heard there might be a formula involving Euler’s totient function $\varphi$, but I'm unsure how to apply it here to count triplets correctly. Can anyone help me derive an efficient formula or function for this?

Wouldn't $(2,4,5)$ qualify for $n=20$ even though $x$ and $y$ are not coprime?

@RossMillikan that is a good point actually
